# Code not showing return

Tags: c, function, return-value

I am trying to write a function definition for function maximum which returns the largest of three integers. But it is not returning the largest.

Here is my code:

```
int maximum( int x, int y, int z ) {
    int max = x;
    if ( y > max )
        max = y;

    if ( z > max )
        max = z;

    return max;
}

int main() {
    maximum(3, 2, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How did you check that?

Comment: I am sorry what do you mean?

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: `maximum(3, 2, 1);` --> `#include <stdio.h>` ... `printf("max=%d",maximum(3, 2, 1));`

Answer (score 2):

The result of  your call to `maximum(3, 2, 1)` is ignored (since your are not using that result). An optimizing compiler is free to ignore that result, and even to avoid the call to `maximum`.

BTW I find that `max3` would be a better name for such a function.

At least, you should print the result of such a function call. So add

```
   printf("max is %d\n", maximum(3, 2, 1));
```

before your `return 0;` in `main` (of course you need `#include <stdio.h>` in the beginning of your source code).

<sup>Hint for newbies: always end the `printf` format string with a newline `\n` or else call `fflush(NULL)` otherwise you'll get unpleasant surprises, because `stdout` is buffered!</sup>

You really should read some more material about programming (or about programming in C). You should enable warning messages in your compiler. And you should learn how to use the debugger. If you are using Linux, compile with `gcc -Wall -g` and learn how to use the `gdb` debugger. So if your source file is `max3homework.c` you would compile it with the

```
gcc -Wall -g max3homework.c -o max3hw
```

command, and you would test it by running `./max3hw` and you would debug it by running `gdb max3hw` and then type appropriate commands to `gdb`.

Comment: Why can maximum(1,2,3,) be ignored?

Comment: @user2085224 - because you didn't do anything with the result. You didn't print it, or store it, or... whatever. You just called the function and ignored the `int` that was returned

Comment: My suggestion would be to ask your teacher, take several hours to read more books, experiment more, etc. Don't expect stack overflow to teach you basic programming skills.

Comment: @user2085224 think of it like this: your code has a function that returns the largest of three integers; you call that function but ignore the return value. It's like asking someone "how are you?" and then running away before they answer. That's not how it works. You have to **wait** and listen for their answer. And then you have to *display* the answer, if you want to see it on the screen. The computer won't magically do anything unless you tell it to do it.

Comment: @user2085224 - Nik's analogy is pretty good, now to put that in terms of Basile's answer: the compiler will look at the code, see you're calling your function and "running away" to the return statement without doing anything with that result. The compiler will probably realize it can save memory/time but just not calling that function and thus will remove it altogether from the executable. As Basile said, if you're using `gcc` add the `-Wall` flag and you'll see a warning for what you did.

Comment: @Mike how do i add the -Wall flag?

Comment: @user2085224 - if you're using `gcc` just add it to your current command (Basile put that in his answer). You're probably doing: `gcc myfile.c` instead do: `gcc -Wall -g myfile.c`, the `-g` adds debug symbols so you can use `gdb` to debug